# Allow typing minus sign at the start of a number during live input validation of integer or float of specific length with up to two decimal digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to allow user to input decimal value with maximim 9 integer digits, and maximum 2 decimals after dot. But also this value can be negative, with "-" sign. Evereything is ok, except this minus sign. Though sites like "regexp.online" show that my regular expression is fine, it does no work in js+jquery. Minus sign fails the checking. See:

```js
$('[name="price"]').bind("change keyup input", function() {
  pricecheck = '^(\\-)?\\d{1,9}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$';
  var regex = new RegExp(pricecheck, 'g');
  if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
    console.log('not in regex');
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="price" style="height:20px;">
```

And fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/obc6qptf/

I tried this "minus" without backslashes - the same result. What is wrong?

Comment: *"And fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/obc6qptf/"* Please use **on-site** Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) rather than off-site resources (although the off-site could be done *in addition* if you want). [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: There are [hundreds of answered questions](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+regular+expression+number) about regular expression validation of numbers. Please refer to the many, many answers to them.

Comment: Ok, but the answer to this one is `const regex = /^-?\d{0,9}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/;`, see https://jsfiddle.net/a50jv2rL/1/. Well, unless `-.55` is not allowed. Then, it is not that straight-forward, `const regex = /^-?\d{0,9}(?:\b\.\d{0,2})?$/;`

Comment: This would all be a lot easier if you actually used a regex syntax instead of a string `/^(\-)?\d{1,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regex that will match the first digit optionally:

```s
const regex = /^-?\d{0,9}(?:\b\.\d{0,2})?$/;
```

Note the `\b` word boundary is used to make sure the `.` separator does not come right after `-`, and if you need that, remove `\b` from the pattern.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - a `-` char (optional)
- `\d{0,9}` - zero to nine digits
- `(?:\b\.\d{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\b` - a word boundary to require a digit (here) before `.`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{0,2}` - zero, one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
$('[name="price"]').bind("change keyup input", function() {
  const regex = /^-?\d{0,9}(?:\b\.\d{0,2})?$/;
  if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="price" style="height:20px;">
```